# Cordova - Use front camera for media capture

Tags: cordova, camera

How do I activate the front camera with cordova for media capture?
I already have the code for activating the default (back) camera, but I cannot find anything about activating the front camera instead.

I am developping an application from which an user can click a button ... and activate the front camera, like a selfie, but not a picture, a video instead.

Is this even possible? if so, how do I do this?
I am using Visual Studio With Cordova Tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

> set CameraOption

```
//Camera.Direction.BACK for back camera
cameraDirection:Camera.Direction.FRONT
```

> But as per documentation,but its not worked for me

```
Camera.Direction = {
    BACK : 0,      // Use the back-facing camera
    FRONT : 1      // Use the front-facing camera
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out the Plugin from Eddy Verbruggen: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin

This has some options which can be configured to use the frontcamera instead of the backcamera.

```
  window.plugins.videocaptureplus.captureVideo(
      captureSuccess, // your success callback
      captureError,   // your error callback
      {
        limit: 1, // the nr of videos to record, default 1 (on iOS always 1)
        duration: duration, // max duration in seconds, default 0, which is 'forever'
        highquality: highquality, // set to true to override the default low quality setting
        frontcamera: frontcamera, // set to true to override the default backfacing camera setting. iOS: works fine, Android: YMMV (#18)
        // you'll want to sniff the useragent/device and pass the best overlay based on that.. assuming iphone here
        portraitOverlay: 'www/img/cameraoverlays/overlay-iPhone-portrait.png', // put the png in your www folder
        landscapeOverlay: 'www/img/cameraoverlays/overlay-iPhone-landscape.png', // not passing an overlay means no image is shown for the landscape orientation
        overlayText: 'Please rotate to landscape for the best result' // iOS only
      }
  );
```

Comment: everything works fine except for the "frontcamera" tag, even when I put 'true', it keeps activating the back camera. Could it be because of my phone or what could be causing this?